# Docker Container Access in Postman

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have below container config in `docker-compose.yml` file

```
  networks:
    my-network:

  client-service:
    container_name: client-service
    image: client-service
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
    ports:
      - 8087:8087
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
    links:
      - cassandra
    networks:
      - my-network
```

I use Docker 19 version, and Mac OS. after reading materials, add entry in `/etc/hosts` file as below,

```
127.0.0.1 host.docker.local
```

When i tried to access `http://host.docker.internal:8087` in postman getting `socket hang up` error in postman. I tried using `localhost:8087` but no luck.

the `my-network` is bridge network. any way to access my container?

Comment: Is the process inside the container listening on port 8087, or somewhere else?  Can you access it using `curl` or other tools?  What you show should work.  (You can't directly access the bridge network, and on MacOS you can't access containers at all expect through the published `ports:`.)

Comment: There is issue with my service,  service started and failed due to DB connectivity, exception occurred, and again one more time started with same port. After reading few details from Google, ```socket hang up``` can occur if the port is busy with a service already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for `socket hang up` issue, so spring boot bean initialised Cassandra connection but not closed.

After few day digging into the code, i forgot to add port number in `application.properties` file. So need to make sure that port should be added in both `docker-compose.yml` and `application.properties` files. It's resolved it.

In your case might be any one as below,

```
- Close the connection if you have opened any for connecting to
   database after your work is done. Most of the times this is the
   reason. 

- You can handle this by using Async or Promise and SetTimeOut
   concepts which will make ur server to wait for response for a given
   time and if its taking too long just return with an error message.
   
- You can create multiple instances of your application on server and
   each instance will handle requests separately. 

- Also if you are developing a small utility you can modify it to fire limited 
   requests after a particular interval.
```